# jQuery/JavaScript: Attach file to file input via custom Dropbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Problem**

I have a custom dropdox, which I can drag and drop files in. I want to be able to assign this file to a pre-existing input via jQuery/JavaScript. How would I do this?

**What i've tried**

I've tried getting the file via `var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;` which works but how do I attach it to the input? I've tried `$('#id_cycle_file')[0].files[0] = file`

```js
  $(document).on("dragover", 'html', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).on("drop", 'html', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    });

    // Drag enter
    $(document).on('dragenter','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box__dragtext").text("Drop here!");
        $(".box__dragbox_background").css({'opacity':'1'})
    });

    // Drag over
    $(document).on('dragover','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box__dragtext").text("Drop here!");
        $(".box__dragbox_background").css({'opacity':'1'})
    });

    $(document).on('dragleave','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box__dragtext").text("Drag files to upload here");
        $(".box__dragbox_background").css('opacity','0')
    });

    // Drop
    $(document).on('drop','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".box__dragtext").text("Uploaded!");
        
        var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        $('#id_cycle_file')[0].files[0] = file
    });
```

```css
  
.box__dragndrop,
.box__uploading,
.box__success,
.box__error {
  display: none;
}

.box__dragbox_background {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition:'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out'
}

.box__dragbox {
    border: 3px dashed #c1c1c1;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.box__dragtext {
    color: grey;
    z-index: 1;
}

.box__thumbnails {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.thumbnail {
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:left;
    display: flex;
}

.thumbnail .text {
    margin: 0 10;
}

.attachment-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.attachment-count-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    right: -4px;
    bottom: -3px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 9px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.thumbnail-remove {
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.thumbnail-remove:hover {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
   <div id="div_id_cycle_file" class="form-group">
      <label for="id_cycle_file" class="">
         Cycle file
      </label>
      <div class="">
        <input type="file" name="cycle_file" class="clearablefileinput form-control-file" id="id_cycle_file">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="qFdmWbf0xwsB0PcPHV8wI0d0b4ctK35CKVmk7fcFoqYysQepQvmVsXmch0b5yl4I">           
    <div class="box__dragbox">
       <div class="box__dragbox_background"></div>
       <p class="box__dragtext jlrFontMediumBold">Drag cycle here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box__uploading">Uploading…</div>
   <div class="box__success">Done!</div>
   <div class="box__error">Error! <span></span>.</div>
</div>
```